# What is the correct way to convert a value that is bit in Sql to Int in C#

Tags: c#, sql, converters

**Question:** What is the right way to convert a value that is a bit in Sql to an Int in C#?

**Objective:** Using Sql2008R2 and C#, convert the value to integer to insert into another table.

**Error:** The following code returns this error. Input string was not in a correct format.

```
    public struct Mystruct
    {
        public Int32 Active
    }

    public static bool ReturnActivity
    {
        String sql = "";

       {
           conn.Open();

           sql = "SELECT " +
                     "database.dbo.table1.Active " +
                 "FROM " +
                     "database.dbo.tabe1 ";

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

           SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           while (dr.Read())
           {
                MyStruct ReturnActivity = new MyStruct();

                ReturnActivity.Active = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());

                SomeArraylist.Add(MyStruct);

           }

                dr.Close();
                conn.Close();

                return true;
     }
```

Thank you in advance for any comments, suggestions or recommendations.

Comment: *Where* is the error happening in this code? Have you debugged to find what the values are?

Comment: the error occurs exactly at the "ReturnActivity.Active = Convert..." It doesn't get to generate a value

Comment: Is your column nullable? If it is, and you don't convert to a nullable int ( `int?` ) then you're bound to get exceptions.

Comment: What is your error exactly?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal the column is not nullable,

Comment: @JNYRanger Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @TristanDescartes Change the `GetValue()` to `GetBoolean(0)` while dropping the `ToString()` and you should be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`GetBoolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getboolean.aspx) method to return the value of a bit column as a `bool`:

```
ReturnActivity.Active = dr.GetBoolean(0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Note that `?…:` is the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx). It will evaluate the boolean expression to the left of the `?` and return the value to the left of the `:` if it is `true`, or the value to the right of the `:` if it is `false`.

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
if (dr.GetBoolean(0))
{
    ReturnActivity.Active = 1;
} else {
    ReturnActivity.Active = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you the GetBoolean was exactly what I was missing

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming it's the line

```
ReturnActivity.Active = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

That is failing. It's failing because `GetValue` returns an `object`, and calling `ToString` on the object (note that it's underlying type is of type `bool`) is returning `"True"` or `"False"`, not the `0` or `1` that you see in sql. Use `GetBoolean` to get it as a bool type, then check the returned value to get either 0 or 1:

```
ReturnActivity.Active = dr.GetBoolean(0) ? 0 : 1;
```

Also, there's a thing called a [`Verbatim String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), where instead of this:

```
sql = "SELECT " +
      "database.dbo.table1.Active " +
      "FROM " +
      "database.dbo.tabe1 ";
```

You can do this:

```
sql = @"SELECT 
            database.dbo.table1.Active
        FROM
            database.dbo.tabe1";
```

Which is much easier to look at and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you pull a `BIT` value from a SQL database you use `GetBoolean()` instead of simply GetValue().  You can then simply pass a boolean value to `Convert.ToInt32(bool b)` instead of a string.  This will return either a 0 or 1 accordingly.

There is no need to convert to a string and then back into an int.

Comment: That makes sense I took your advice and  dropped the ToString